# Реализация поиска простых делителей

Tags: c++, алгоритм, математика, инспекция-кода, факторизация

Всем привет, написал код по поиску простых чисел и запоминания этих чисел и их степеней:

```
int t = 0;
    int i = 2;
    int k = 1;
    int z = 0;
    vector<int> q(10);
    vector<int> ak(10);
    int l=phi(p);
    t = l;

    while (i <= t)
    {
        if (t%i == 0)
        {
            t = t / i;
            q[z] = i;
            ak[z] = k;
            k++;
            if (t%i != 0)
            {
                z++;
                k = 1;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            i = i + 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Получилось очень много кода. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно оптимизировать

Comment: Это НЕ очень много кода. Даже не просто много кода...

Comment: while => for, if += while, q,ak => vector<pair<...>>, (10) => push_back, а ответ может потом напишу.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Я бы не сказал, что его много, его просто мало :), но он не очень удобен и эффективен.
Держать два массива для делителей и степеней - неудобно, тем более что это тесно взаимосвязанные вещи. Проще использовать `map`.

Далее, перебирать все делители тоже смысла не имеет - ну зачем после проверки деления на 2 проверять, например, деление на 6? Идеально для скорости - хранить массив простых чисел и работать с ним; но если это кажется напрасной тратой места :) - то хотя бы проходите просто по нечетным числам, вынеся работу с двойками отдельно.

Словом, я бы предложил [такое](https://ideone.com/ZIgRQF):

```
map<unsigned int, unsigned int> factorize(unsigned int n)
{
    map<unsigned int, unsigned int> m;
    while(n > 1 && n%2 == 0)
    {
        m[2]++;
        n /= 2;
    }
    if (n > 1) for(unsigned int i = 3; i*i <= n;)
    {
        if (n%i == 0) { m[i]++; n /= i; continue; }
        i += 2;
    }
    if (n > 1) m[n]++;
    return m;
}
```

Еще раз - я бы этот код дополнил таблицей простых чисел...

И еще - малое количество кода - не всегда означает эффективное решение. Нередко лучше написать в два раза больше кода, но получить в несколько раз более быстрое решение.

Comment: я думал насчет map. Но дальше как к нему обращаться?. Например мне нужен первый делитель.Я к нему уже не смогу обратиться, как m[0].

Comment: Зачем делать медленный map, когда нужен просто вектор пар?

Comment: Что значит "первый"? Наименьший? `m.begin()->first`. Посмотрите по ссылке в ответе - там полностью работоспособный пример с выводом делителей.

Comment: спасибо, понял)

Comment: @Qwertiy Ну, можно и так. Не думаю, однако, что для реальных делителей (там что-то типа логарифма должно получаться) это критично. Но, конечно же, можно и так.

Comment: Мне нужно будет работать с очень большими числами, лучше использовать map или vector? И для больших размеров массива можно использовать auto переменную?

Comment: Да не будет у очень больших чисел большого количества делителей. Никак не дольше логарифма по основанию 2 от числа, как сами понимаете. Для 64-битного числа - не более 64 штук, на таком количестве разница заметна не будет. А работать с вектором сложнее - нужно отслеживать последний элемент, проверять его...  `m[i]++` гораздо проще :)

Comment: @Qwertiy Нет, не буду писать с вектором. С ним - нужно постоянно отслеживать, что в последнем элементе, записан ли старый делитель или нет, или нужно добавлять новый элемент... С `map` это все превращается в `m[i]++`. А поскольку даже для 64-битного числа элементов заведомо меньше 64 - то разница будет просто незаметна...

Comment: Я вот не смог понять все таки как обращаться к элементам map. Мне нужно заполнить матрицу(или что-то подобное, пока раздумываю). Где количество строк зависит от размера map(это легко через size). А длина строки зависит от делителя. Вот вторым циклом for, я не знаю как указать делитель

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70563/discussion-between--and-harry).

Comment: до n все числа не нужно проверять... достаточно до sqrt(n)...

Comment: @Fat-Zer Ну да, только надо добавить тогда внесение самого n.

Comment: Да ничего сложного с `map` нет. Если вым их надо перебрать в цикле - `for(auto n : m)` и все, в теле `n.first` будет простой делитель, а `m.second` - его степень. Если у вас С++17, то можно вообще так: `for(auto [p,k] : m)
        {
            cout << p << "^" << k << "  ";
        }`

Comment: @Harry, нет, нужно не последний элемент отслеживать, а цикл переписать и добавить while. Посмотри мой коммент к вопросу.

Comment: @Qwertiy Ну, как у вас найдется время написать - я бы ознакомился. Видно, дело к вечеру, что-то не вижу, как это сделать легко и просто, не раздувая код.

Comment: @Harry, готово.

Comment: @Qwertiy Ага, теперь понял :) Но, по-моему, с `map`ом все же проще...

Comment: @Harry, но он неэффективный...

Comment: Для десятка чисел? Ладно, по свободе проверю, сейчас времени нет...

Answer (score 2):

Итак, сравниваем два метода. Полный код [тут](http://vpaste.net/K6zbQ). Вкратце - чтоб не просто делители считать, но еще и использовать как-то наши `vector` и `map`, я еще и считаю общую сумму делителей и их степеней. Так, первое, что в голову пришло. Ну, и пришлось переписать немного код Qwertiy, чтоб лишнего поменьше делал...

Проверяю примерно так:

```
{
    muTimer mu;
    unsigned int total = 0;
    for(unsigned int n = 2; n < N; ++n)
    {
        auto m = Qwertiy(n);
        for(auto [p,k] : m) total += p + k;
    }
    mu.stop();
    cout << "Qwertiy: " << total << " for " << mu.duration<muTimer::ms>() << " ms\n";
}
```

Заряжаем на 5 миллионов чисел:

```
Harry  : 2479739720 for 4377 ms
Qwertiy: 2479739720 for 4056 ms
```

Компилировал VC++2017, 64-разрядное приложение, запускал на своей Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-2500 CPU @ 3.30 GHz 8G RAM --- Windows 7 x64.

Разница есть, но назвать ее критичной я не могу :) Вот если дописать резервирование памяти для вектора - тогда да, разница с 10% вырастает до 20%.

Кстати, замена `map` на `unordered_map` только ухудшает дело.

**Update**

А вот очень показательный пример - работаем с большими числами; код с проверкой подряд и код с проверкой с помощью готовой таблицы простых чисел - см. [тут](http://vpaste.net/AU3a4) - показывает, как эффективнее факторизовать:

```
Harry    : 647967786 for 9054 ms
PHarry   : 647967786 for 105 ms
Qwertiy  : 647967786 for 8975 ms
VecPrimes: 647967786 for 95 ms
```

Кстати, для больших чисел, когда главное - не во времени доступа к контейнеру, а в вычислениях - разница оказывается невелика.

Comment: [Пошли в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70638/discussion-on-answer-by-harry----) :)

Answer (score 1):

https://ideone.com/HVD59h

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

vector < pair <unsigned, unsigned> > dividers(unsigned n)
{
  vector < pair <unsigned, unsigned> > res;

  if (n <= 1)
    res.push_back(make_pair(n, 1));

  for (unsigned q=2; q*q<=n; ++q)
  {
    if (n % q == 0)
    {
      unsigned d;
      for (d=0; !(n%q); ++d) n/=q;
      res.push_back(make_pair(q, d));
    }
  }

  if (n > 1)
    res.push_back(make_pair(n, 1));

  return res;
}

string fragment(const pair <unsigned, unsigned> &p)
{
  char res[256];
  sprintf(res, p.second==1 ? "%d" : "%d^%d", p.first, p.second);
  return res;
}

void print(const vector < pair <unsigned, unsigned> > &v)
{
  transform(v.begin(), --v.end(), ostream_iterator<string>(cout, " * "), fragment);
  cout << fragment(*v.rbegin()) << endl;
}

int main()
{
  print(dividers(126));
  print(dividers(1));
  print(dividers(17));
  print(dividers(128));
  print(dividers(0));
  print(dividers(121));

  return 0;
}
```

```
2 * 3^2 * 7
1
17
2^7
0
11^2
```