# Найти сумму простых делителей числа N

Tags: c++, c, алгоритм, простые-числа, теория-чисел

**При вводе любого значения ничего не выводится**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main()
{
    int n, sum = 1;
    if (scanf("%lf", n) == 0)
    {
        printf("Incorrect input value");
    }
    else
    {
        for (int i = 2; i <= n; i++)
        {
            int count = 0;
            if (n % i == 0)
            {
                for (int j = 2; j <= i - 1; j++)
                {
                    if (i % j == 0)
                    {
                        count += 1;
                        break;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        sum += i;
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                break;
            }   
        }
    }
    printf("%i", sum);
}
```

Comment: А вы ничего и не вводите: `scanf("%lf", n)` Для ввода целочисленного `n` надо `scanf("%d", &n)`

Comment: Исправил. ничего не поменялось(

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/595966/195342 , https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/761020/195342

Answer (score 4, accepted):

У Вас есть несколько логических ошибок в коде:

1. Почему переменная `sum` инициализированная значением `1`? По идее должно быть `0`.
2. Ввод значения через `scanf` происходит по адресу. К тому же у Вас она ожидает значение с плавающей запятой, а не целое значение. Корректный вызов примерно такой: `scanf("%d", &n)`.
3. Добавление делителя к сумме должно происходить после проверки числа на простоту, а не в ней. Т.е. строка `sum += i;` должна быть за пределами вложенного цикла и выполняться только если `count == 0`.
4. Веткой `else {break;}` Вы завершаете искать делители после первого не простого делителя. Эта ветка вообще не нужна.

По итогу Ваш код должен иметь примерно такой вид:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int n, sum = 0;
    if (scanf("%d", &n) == 0)
    {
        printf("Incorrect input value");
    }
    else
    {
        for (int i = 2;i <= n; i++)
        {
            int count = 0;
            if (n % i == 0)
            {
                for (int j = 2; j <= i - 1; j++)
                {
                    if (i % j == 0)
                    {
                        count += 1;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (count == 0)
                {
                    sum += i;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    printf("%i", sum);
    return 0;
}
```

Это Ваш код с минимальными изменениями. В таком виде его не очень просто понять с первого взгляда из-за непонятных имён переменных и нагромождении всего в одной функции. Вот для примера Я набросал код, который не тянет на идеальную реализацию, но понять его намного проще (правда без ввода данных с клавиатуры):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

// Функция проверки числа на простоту
bool isPrime(int n)
{
    for(int i = 2; i * i <= n; i++)
    {
        if (n % i == 0)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

int main(void)
{
    // Наше входное значение
    int input = 122;
    
    // Сразу инициализируем сумму двойкой, если наше число чётное, 
    // иначе инициализируем нулём
    unsigned long long sum = input % 2 ? 0ULL : 2ULL;

    // Цикл начинается с 3, потому что двойку мы уже учли в инициализации суммы 
    // и теперь удобно идти только по нечётным числам
    for (int currentDivisor = 3; currentDivisor <= input; currentDivisor += 2)
    {
        // Если число делится на текущий проверяемый делитель без остатка
        // и этот делитель является простым числом, то добавляем его к сумме
        if (input % currentDivisor == 0 && isPrime(currentDivisor))
        {
            sum += currentDivisor;
        }
    }
    printf("Sum: %llu\n", sum);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Особо код не тестил. Если где-то налажал, то дайте знать.

Comment: А какой смысл проверять делители на простоту? Просто делить число на делитель, пока делится. Тогда делители автоматически будут только простыми...

Comment: @Harry Я просто сделал то же что и ТС, просто привёл в нормальный вид. Не хотел менять алгоритм, а просто показал, что тот же код можно сделать более понятным.

Answer (score 2):

Я бы делал так:

```
int main()
{
    int n, sum = 0;
    if (scanf("%d",&n)==0) return 1;
    if (n%2 == 0)
    {
        sum += 2;
        while(n%2 == 0) n/=2;       // Делим, пока делится.
    }

    for (int i = 3; i*i <= n; i+=2) // Только по нечетным, четным n быть  уже не может
    {
        if (n%i == 0)
        {
            sum += i;
            while(n%i == 0) n /= i; // Делим, пока делится. Так и n уменьшается
        }                           //  что ускоряет работу...
    }
    if (n > 1) sum += n;            // Если после этого что-то осталось — то это простое
    printf("%d\n", sum);
}
```

Но встает вопрос о *кратных* делителях. Их не надо учитывать? Например, 18 = 2*3*3. Надо ли 3 считать один раз или два?

Comment: На некоторых [входных данных](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6ffb76fd9cb112b1) поведение приведённого кода не определено из-за знакового целочисленного переполнения здесь: `i*i <= n`.

Comment: @wololo Если это так важно, замените на `i <= sqrt(n)`. Или измените тип на `long long`. Или воспользуйтесь длинной арифметикой. Знаете, если откровенно — то я считаю это не более чем придирками...

Comment: Не знал, что ваши ответы нельзя критиковать, простите.

Comment: @wololo Нет, не прощу ни за что! :)

Comment: "что ускоряет работу" - создаёт ложное впечатление что это только оптимизация. А делить нужно чтобы алгоритм в дальнейшем не находил составные делители.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy Обратите внимание на комментарий — *Так **и** `n` уменьшается* — т.е. это чисто побочный эффект. Если бы я делал это только для эффективности, я бы написал иначе...